# primefaces fileUpload with image preview of the file using simple mode

Tags: jsf, primefaces

form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <p:fileUpload value="#{testController.file}" 
                  mode="simple"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  
</h:form>
```

is there any way to add an image preview of the file that is to be uploaded after choosing a file? I know advance mode of fileUpload does this job, but i need it to be in simple mode.